# WebView определить, что нужно открыть URL в новом окне

Tags: android, android-sdk

У меня есть простое приложение с `WebView`.
Можно ли каким-либо образом в экземпляре `WebChromeClient` или `WebClient` определить, что страницу необходимо открыть в новом окне? (к примеру, новое окно нужно открыть, в случае перехода по ссылке вида: `<a target="_blank" href="...">`)

```
    mWebView = new WebView(activity);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {...});
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebClient() {...});
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```